# What does calling map with one argument do in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, currying, clojure-core

In Clojure, what does calling `map` with one argument, like this:

```
(map inc) ;=> #object[clojure.core$map$fn__4549 0x1decdb9d "clojure.core$map$fn__4549@1decdb9d"]
```

...do / return? Because it doesn't do auto currying as expected, so the following two expressions are not equivalent:

```
;; E1
((map inc) [100 200 300]) ;=> #object[clojure.core$map$fn__4549$fn__4550 0x1b0c8974 "clojure.core$map$fn__4549$fn__4550@1b0c8974"]

;; E2
((partial map inc) [100 200 300]) ;=> (101 201 301)
```

...and the documentation says nothing.

**So what IS the mysterious function returned by `(map inc)` and other similar expressions?**

Comment: Which version are you using? `(map inc)` throws an `ArityException` on 1.6.0.

Comment: It's a transducer. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317325/can-someone-explain-clojure-transducers-to-me-in-simple-terms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317325/can-someone-explain-clojure-transducers-to-me-in-simple-terms)

Comment: @user5187212 ah, so the mythical transducers... guess I'll have to read up on them

Answer (score 4):

calling map with a single argument in clojure 1.7+ returns a [transducer](http://clojure.org/transducers) that can be composed with other transducers and eventually a call to `into` or some other transducing thing.

I recommend this [video first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mTbuzafcII), and then [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KqUvG8HPYo)

This allows you to use all the clojure sequence abstractions without the computer spending a lot of time building intermediate sequences.

In clojure less than 1.7 it will throw an arity exception