# Scheme - sum the squares of even-valued elements in a list

Tags: list, scheme, filtering, singly-linked-list, fold

I want to be able to sum the squares of the even elements in the list, however my current code only sums the elements, not the squares. Does anyone know of any modifications that can be made to make this to sum the squares of the even-valued elements in the list?

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (if
    (null? elemList)
    0
    (+ (car elemList) (sum (cdr elemList)))
  )
)
```

My input would be:

```
(sum-evens (list 1 2 3 4))
```

Output would be:

```
20
```

Which is `(2*2) + (4*4)`.

If possible, it would be good to see both a recursive and iterative solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: by "even elements", do you mean the elements that occur at the even-numbered indices? Or do you mean the elements that are themselves even?

Comment: @pnkfelix i meant elements divisible by 2 (the even values not indicies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities, either we implement the recursion from scratch:

```
(define (sum elemList)
  (cond ((null? elemList) 0)
        ((even? (car elemList))
         (+ (* (car elemList) (car elemList))
            (sum (cdr elemList))))
        (else (sum (cdr elemList)))))
```

Or we use built-in procedures, defining helpers as needed. This strategy is known as using ["sequences as conventional interfaces"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.3):

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (sum elemList)
  (apply +
         (map square
              (filter even? elemList))))
```

In Scheme, the preferred way is the second one, because we must not reinvent the wheel when we have procedures that already do the job for us. Either way, it works as expected:

```
(sum '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
=> 220
```

Comment: Very well explained, i really appreciate it. Exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

(sidenote, to see this post with emphasis but without syntax highlighting, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45851399/14))

With Racket's *left fold* function,

```
(define (foldl cons z ls) 
  (if (null? ls) 
    z 
    (foldl cons (cons (car ls) z)           ; NB! args order
                (cdr ls))))
```

we can easily implement the summing of a list (`(foldl + 0 xs)`), *or* the taking of the squares, *or* the filtering, separately.

It is also easy to nest them, so that one works with the results of the other (as is shown in the other answers), but that means *three* separate list traversals are performed and *two* interim lists are built in addition to the results list,

```
(define (sqr x) (* x x)) 

(define (foo-3 xs)
  (foldl  +  0 
    --   ^^^            --   vvvv
    (foldl  (lambda (x acc) (cons (sqr x) acc))  '() 
      (foldl  (lambda (x acc) (if (even? x) (cons x acc) acc))  '() 
        xs))))
```

But actually, folding (or, *"reducing"*) a list with a *reducer* function (like **`+`**) replaces the list's **`cons`** with that reducer function's application anyway, so why not just go ahead and *use that reducer* in place of that **`cons`** in the inner fold, in the first place? This means that the nested folds can be *fused* together as

```
(define (foo-2 xs)
    (foldl  (lambda (x acc) (+  (sqr x) acc))   0 
      --    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ vvvv
      (foldl  (lambda (x acc) (if (even? x) (cons x acc) acc))  '() 
        xs)))
```

and, further, as

```
(define (foo-1 xs)   ; one traversal, tail-recursive, iterative!
      (foldl  (lambda (x acc) 
                 (if (even? x) (+ (sqr x) acc) acc))   0 
        xs))
```

thus *deriving* the *iterative* one-traversal function that doesn't create any superfluous interim data at all, which *could* otherwise be hand-coded relatively easily, perhaps as a *recursive* variant seen in the other answers, but in any case hand coding is in general harder and prone to errors. Ideally, we would like to be able to easily write code which is self-evidently correct -- *and* efficient. This could be achieved by a framework to compose / fuse those separate folds semi-automatically.

Thus the need to abstract the `cons` can be seen here, so that it can be easily manipulated, replaced. In other words, we want

```
(lambda (x acc) (cons (sqr x) acc))               ==:  ((mapping  sqr) cons)
(lambda (x acc) (if (even? x) (cons x acc) acc))  ==:  ((filtering even?) cons)
```

thus arriving at what's known as *"transducers"*, i.e. reducer functions' transformers:

```
(define (((mapping  f) kons) x acc) (kons (f x) acc))           ; "mapping" transducer
(define (((filtering p) kons) x acc) (if (p x) (kons x acc) acc))    ; "filtering" one

(define (foo xs)

  (foldl + 0 
    (foldl ((mapping sqr) cons) '() 
      (foldl ((filtering even?) cons) '() 
        xs)))
  =
    (foldl ((mapping sqr) +) 0                  ; replace the constructor!
      (foldl ((filtering even?) cons) '()       ;   and the sentinel value
        xs))
  =
      (foldl ((filtering even?) ((mapping sqr) +))   0  ; and again!
           ; (lambda (x acc)                    ; look ma, no cons!
           ;   (if  (even? x)  (+ (sqr x) acc)  acc)) 
        xs)
  )
```

The `(f (g x))` pattern is abstracted as the *functional composition*,

```
(define ((compose1 f g) x)
    (f (g x)))
```

so that `(f (g x))` is `((compose1 f g) x)`. With it, we can compose however many transducers we might need into one combined transducer, expecting of one argument which is a reducer function.

```
(define (transduce-list tducr r z xs)
  (foldl                            ; lists are reduced with foldl
         (tducr r)                  ; the full reducer is created by applying
         z xs))                     ;   the transducer to the final reducer

(define (foo xs)                    ; sum the squares of evens in a list
  (transduce-list                   ; by transducing the list
       (compose1                    ;   with the transducer composed from
           (filtering even?)        ;     a filtering step and
           (mapping sqr))           ;     a mapping step
       + 0 xs))                     ;   with + as the final reducer
```

and that's that!

---

So we have

```
(define (sqr1 x) (+ 1 (* x x)))     ; for clearer testing results

> (foldl ((mapping sqr1) cons) '() '(1 2 3 4))
'(17 10 5 2)
> (foldl ((mapping sqr1) +) 0 '(1 2 3 4))
> 34
```

`((mapping sqr1) cons)`, just like `cons` itself, is a function of two arguments, so can be used as the *reducer function* argument to `foldl`.

Having `(define g ((mapping sqr1) cons))` is the same as

```
(define (g x acc)
      (cons (sqr1 x) acc))
```

And with `filtering` we  have

```
> (foldl ((filtering even?) +) 0 '(1 2 3 4))
> 6
> (foldl ((mapping sqr1) ((filtering even?) cons)) '() '(1 2 3 4))
> '(10 2)
> (foldl ((filtering even?) ((mapping sqr1) cons)) 0 '(1 2 3 4))
> '(17 5 . 0)
```

So, `((mapping sqr1) ((filtering even?) cons))` is a reducer, where `(mapping sqr1)` uses `((filtering even?) cons)` as *its* reducer. And *that* is `(filtering even?)` using `cons` as *its* – final in the chain – reducer function:

```
(define g
  ((mapping sqr1) ((filtering even?) cons)))
=
(define (g x acc)
  (let ((f ((filtering even?) cons)))
    (f (sqr1 x) acc)))                          ; by definition of mapping
= 
(define (g x acc)
  (define (f y acc)
    (if (even? y)  (cons y acc)  acc))          ; by definition of filtering
  (f (sqr1 x) acc))
= 
(define (g x acc)
  (let ((y (sqr1 x)))
    (if (even? y)  (cons y acc)  acc)))          ; by application rule
```

Mmm, mapping, filtering, and consing are all *automagically* rolled up into *one* reducer function for us as if we've written it ourselves! Better yet, `foldl` being tail-recursive, the overall function is iterative and performs just one list traversal – because the three reducer functions were combined into one.

Some more testing:

```
(define (bar xs)
  (foldl ((compose
                (filtering even?)    ; filtering is done first
                (mapping sqr1))
           cons)
          0 xs))

(define (baz xs)
  (foldl ((compose
                (mapping sqr1)       ; mapping is done first
                (filtering even?))
           cons)
         '() xs))
```

so that

```
> (bar '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(17 5 . 0)
> (baz '(1 2 3 4 5))
'(26 10 2)
```

Comment: sick **bolding** skills in the code blocks <3 oh and this answer is awesome – gives the reader authentic feeling of discovering transducers

Comment: @naomik thank you very much, I appreciate it. embarrassing as that is, I really did, discover them, for me, here (1). I've searched and tried to read a lot, but it was just an impenetrable wall of words of enchanting magic. And with Haskellers it was the other way round, incomprehensible type wizardry. In reality, if one just goes with code instead of words, it's crystal clear. :) -- (1) almost; first I realized - in Haskell - that `transduce xf op z xs = foldr (xf op) z xs` - no one even tells you this simplest bit! - but here I realized that it all comes from *fold fusion*.

Comment: don't feel embarrassed- i've stalked you for long enough to know how insanely smart you are. i updated my answer to include what i understand about transducers such that it might help you along further. i hope it helps ^_^

Comment: thank you, that's very kind of you. I think you're misoverestimating me, :) you need only look at the edit history of this post to see why. but I'm trying. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (sum ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      0
      (if (even? (car ls))
          (+ (square (car ls)) (sum (cdr ls)))
          (sum (cdr ls)))))
```

where

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))
```

sum the squares of the even elements. If you sum the elements of the list without doing anything, of course the answer cannot be the answer to your question.

What's more, one may implement this procedure in this way:

```
(define (sum ls)
  (reduce +
          0
          (map square
               (filter even?
                       ls))))
```

where `map`, `filter` and `reduce` are the common meanings(you can try it in mit-scheme). This do the same thing, however this is more readable, and things like cdr recursion are optimized. The second chapter in SICP(Structure and Interpretation
of Computer Programs) introduced this methodology of programming.

Comment: Thanks for the response, also a great solution :)

Answer (score 1):

**or with SICP style streams !**

if this interests you, see section **3.5** of *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (Sussman, Abelson)*

the stream functions here work much like the transducers described in @WillNess's answer – ie, streams do not require multiple iterations thru the data

all stream *procedures* here are recursive but evolve a linear iterative *process*

it's worth noting that `cons-stream` is a special form that does not immediately evaluate it's second argument

```
#lang sicp

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define stream-car car)

(define (stream-cdr s)
  (force (cdr s)))

(define (integers x)
  (cons-stream x (integers (inc x))))

(define (stream-filter f s)
  (cond ((stream-null? s) the-empty-stream)
        ((f (stream-car s)) (cons-stream (stream-car s) (stream-filter f (stream-cdr s))))
        (else (stream-filter f (stream-cdr s)))))

(define (stream-map f s)
  (if (stream-null? s)
      the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream (f (stream-car s)) (stream-map f (stream-cdr s)))))

(define (stream-take n s)
  (cond ((stream-null? s) the-empty-stream)
        ((> n 0) (cons-stream (stream-car s) (stream-take (dec n) (stream-cdr s))))
        (else the-empty-stream)))

(define (stream-reduce f acc s)
  (if (stream-null? s)
      acc
      (stream-reduce f (f acc (stream-car s)) (stream-cdr s))))

(stream-reduce + 0
  (stream-map square
    (stream-filter even?
      (stream-take 10
        (integers 1)))))
;; => 220
```

---

**transducers**

it is with immense affection i present this portion of the answer for @WillNess

i was [introduced to transducers](https://medium.com/@drboolean/monoidal-contravariant-functors-are-actually-useful-1032211045c4) thru a person who has a knack for distilling the overwhelmingly complex down to the miraculously simple – as a labour of love, i've adapted some of the code/ideas presented (originally in javascript) to scheme

each `;; [section]` defines an abstraction barrier

**edit:** removed special forms for `cons-cont` and `cons-trans` – macro didn't critically improve code readability

```
#lang sicp

;; [procedure]
(define (compose f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))

;; [list]
(define (foldl f acc xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      acc
      (foldl f (f acc (car xs)) (cdr xs))))

;; [continuation]
(define cons-cont
  identity)

(define the-empty-cont
  identity)

(define cont-concat
  compose)

(define (cont-concat-all cs)
  (foldl cont-concat the-empty-cont cs))

;; [trans]
(define (cons-trans f)
  (cons-cont (lambda (cont) (lambda (acc x) (f cont acc x)))))

(define the-empty-trans
  the-empty-cont) ;; unused in this program, but completes implementation

(define trans-concat
  cont-concat)    ;; unused in this program, but completes implementation

(define trans-concat-all
  cont-concat-all)

;; [transducer]
(define (cons-transducer . ts)
  (lambda (f acc xs)
    (foldl ((trans-concat-all ts) f) acc xs)))

(define (mapper f)
  (cons-trans (lambda (next acc x) (next acc (f x)))))

(define (filterer f)
  (cons-trans (lambda (next acc x) (if (f x) (next acc x) acc))))

(define (effector f)
  (cons-trans (lambda (next acc x) (f x) (next acc x))))

(define (logger s)
  (effector (lambda (x) (display s) (display " ") (display x) (display "\n"))))

;; [main]
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (main xs)
  ((cons-transducer (logger "input")
                    (filterer even?)
                    (logger "filtered")
                    (mapper square)
                    (logger "squared"))
   + 0 xs))

(main '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
```

output

```
input 1
input 2
filtered 2
squared 4
input 3
input 4
filtered 4
squared 16
input 5
input 6
filtered 6
squared 36
input 7
input 8
filtered 8
squared 64
input 9
input 10
filtered 10
squared 100
=> 220
```

Comment: I *love* streams... the difference though is that with transducers there really is just one processing function, *one* combined (... or *composed*) "reducer". then the type of the data source is determined by the type of fold in use -- one for lists, another for channels (apparently), etc. And the type of result is determined by the final reducer op (like `+`) -- but the transducers are the same. So it's really nice; gives us new language. Rich Hickey is a very smart guy. :) -- I'm very intrigued by "data flow" paradigm, in general. Streams feel like implicit DF, tducers like more explicit DF.

Comment: @WillNess your comment here makes perfect sense to me and is represented well (i hope) in the update to my answer – unrelated: to my surprise `cont-concat` is equivalent to `(lambda (f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x)))` which is equivalent to `compose` – my fascination with this matches my bewilderment

Comment: @WillNess I think the macro was actually hurting the readability of this program - i made an edit that removes it. as a result, the simplified implementation of `cont` is truly blowing my mind

Comment: I've worked through the Scheme code now, and it results in more or less the same definitions as mine. :) JS, I don't quite read. :)

Comment: yep, conceptually, it all comes down to a `fold` of `fold`s in the end, right ? Thanks for sharing, Will ^_^