# Returning the sum of positive squares

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to edit the current program I have

```
(define (sumofnumber n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (+ n (sumofnumber (modulo n 2 )))))
```

so that it returns the sum of an `n` number of positive squares. For example if you inputted in 3 the program would do 1+4+9 to get 14. I have tried using modulo and other methods but it always goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base case is incorrect (the square of zero is zero), and so is the recursive step (why are you taking the modulo?) and the actual operation (where are you squaring the value?). This is how the procedure should look like:

```
(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0 
      (+ (* n n)
         (sum-of-squares (- n 1)))))
```

Comment: Racket with camelCase?

Answer (score 1):

A definition using composition rather than recursion. Read the comments from bottom to top for the procedural logic:

```
(define (sum-of-squares n)
  (foldl +                             ; sum the list
         0 
         (map (lambda(x)(* x x))       ; square each number in list
              (map (lambda(x)(+ x 1))  ; correct for range yielding 0...(n - 1)
                   (range n)))))       ; get a list of numbers bounded by n
```

I provide this because you are well on your way to understanding the idiom of recursion. Composition is another of Racket's idioms worth exploring and often covered after recursion in educational contexts.

Sometimes I find composition easier to apply to a problem than recursion. Other times, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You're not squaring anything, so there's no reason to expect that to be a sum of squares.

Write down how you got `1 + 4 + 9` with `n = 3` (`^` is exponentiation):

```
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2
```

This is

```
(sum-of-squares 2) + 3^2
```

or

```
(sum-of-squares (- 3 1)) + 3^2
```

that is,

```
(sum-of-squares (- n 1)) + n^2
```

Notice that modulo does not occur anywhere, nor do you add `n` to anything.

(And the square of 0 is 0 , not 1.)

Answer (score 0):

You can break the problem into small chunks. 
1. Create a list of numbers from 1 to n 
2. Map a square function over list to square each number 
3. Apply + to add all the numbers in squared list

```
(define (sum-of-number n)
          (apply + (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) (sequence->list (in-range 1 (+ n 1))))))

> (sum-of-number 3)
    14
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect opportunity for using the *transducers* technique.

Calculating the sum of a list is a fold. Map and filter are folds, too. Composing several folds together in a nested fashion, as in `(sum...(filter...(map...sqr...)))`, leads to multiple (here, three) list traversals.

But [when the nested folds are fused, their reducing functions combine in a nested fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851399/849891), giving us a *one-traversal* fold instead, with the one *combined* reducer function:

```
(define (((mapping  f) kons) x acc) (kons (f x) acc))         ; the "mapping" transducer
(define (((filtering p) kons) x acc) (if (p x) (kons x acc) acc))  ; the "filtering" one

(define (sum-of-positive-squares n) 
  (foldl ((compose (mapping sqr)                        ; ((mapping sqr)
                   (filtering (lambda (x) (> x 0))))    ;    ((filtering {> _ 0})
          +) 0 (range (+ 1 n))))                        ;      +))

; > (sum-of-positive-squares 3)
; 14
```

Of course `((compose f g) x)` is the same as `(f (g x))`. The combined / "composed" (pun intended) reducer function is created just by substituting the arguments into the definitions, as

```
        ((mapping sqr)  ((filtering {> _ 0})  +))
       =
        ( (lambda (kons)
             (lambda (x acc) (kons (sqr x) acc)))
           ((filtering {> _ 0})  +))
       =
        (lambda (x acc)   
           ( ((filtering {> _ 0})  +)
            (sqr x) acc)) 
       =
        (lambda (x acc)   
           ( ( (lambda (kons)
                 (lambda (x acc) (if ({> _ 0} x) (kons x acc) acc)))
               +)
            (sqr x) acc)) 
       =
        (lambda (x acc)   
           ( (lambda (x acc) (if (> x 0) (+ x acc) acc))
            (sqr x) acc)) 
       =
        (lambda (x acc)   
           (let ([x (sqr x)] [acc acc])
             (if (> x 0) (+ x acc) acc)))
```

which looks almost as something a programmer would write. As an exercise,

```
        ((filtering {> _ 0})  ((mapping sqr)  +))
       = 
        ( (lambda (kons)
            (lambda (x acc) (if ({> _ 0} x) (kons x acc) acc)))
         ((mapping sqr)  +))
       = 
        (lambda (x acc) 
          (if (> x 0) (((mapping sqr)  +) x acc) acc))
       = 
        (lambda (x acc) 
          (if (> x 0) (+ (sqr x) acc) acc))
```

So instead of writing the fused reducer function definitions ourselves, which as every human activity is error-prone, we can *compose* these reducer functions from more atomic "transformations" nay *transducers*.

Works in DrRacket.